# MTLBuffer contents causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, metal

I created an buffer filled in by an array of float values. Unfortunately, when I try to query its `contents()` property (when I was trying to debug a problem), I was getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Here's the code:

```
let inputData  = [Float32](repeatElement(5, count: 16384)) // Declaration

// Declaration of the buffer and filling contents...
inputBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: inputData, length: MemoryLayout<Float32>.size * inputData.count, options: MTLResourceOptions()) 

// Crash occurs here:
let contents = inputBuffer.contents().load(as: [Float32].self)
```

I would like to know why the crash occurs. Other similar buffer declarations have worked correctly, so I guess this might be an issue with accessing the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the array contents, using the `load` method, you need to specify the array *element type* (and an optional offset) instead. For instance:

```
let firstElement = inputBuffer.contents().load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: Float.self)
```

and so on. You were trying to load the first element as a `[Float]` which might explain the crash.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. So if I want the entire array, is there any function? Or do I iterate over the number of elements while changing the offset?

Comment: @AdilPatel You are welcome ;) Pls see Matthijs answer for a way to get the entire array back...

Answer (score 1):

To get the entire array, you can do:

```
let count = buffer.length / MemoryLayout<Float>.stride
var output = [Float](repeating: 0, count: count)
_ = output.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
  memcpy(ptr.baseAddress, buffer.contents(), buffer.length)
}
```